# Angular dynamic route outlets not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a simple route config

```
const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'route',
    outlet: 'outlet',
    component: TestComponent,
  }
];
```

What I want to do is each time `create router outlet` button is clicked, update current app route config with a new route similar to existing route above but with different outlet name. Create a new route outlet with name attribute set to `outlet-1`

```
 const appRoutes: Route[] = [
      {
        path: 'route',
        outlet: 'outlet',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'route',
        outlet: 'outlet-1',
        component: TestComponent,
      }
    ];

<router-outlet name="outlet-1"/>
```

When I navigate to this new route outlet, `TestComponent` should be rendered below respective outlet.

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { ['outlet-1']: ['route'] } } ]);
```

I am able to achieve what I described above but **test component is created multiple times.**

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qds99g?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

open brower console

click on the button once -> `test component constructor.` logged once.

click on the button 2nd time -> `test component constructor.` logged 2 times.

click on the button 3rd time -> `test component constructor.` logged 3 times.

etc..

Ideally message should be logged once per button click. what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After redefining a router via `resetConfig()`, Angular re-renders all the components into the routes again.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to identify the root cause to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve it use

`this.router.config.push(newRoute);`

instead of

`this.router.resetConfig([...this.router.config, newRoute]);`.

Here is the updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2ta4yn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Also, if route contains child routes then parent routes component (in this case `TestComponent`) must contain `router-outlet` in its template else child routes will not render.